# Step 3 script `_` exited with status code 1 - Codemagic

Tags: android, flutter, cicd, codemagic

I have monorepo that contains Flutter apps. In my parent project I have `melos` installed and this is my `codemagic.yaml`:

```
workflows:
  test-app-workflow-android:
    name: Test App workflow (Android)
    working_directory: $PWD/apps/test_app
    instance_type: mac_mini_m1
    max_build_duration: 60
    environment:
      flutter: master
      java: 1.8
    triggering:
      events:
        - push
      branch_patterns:
        - pattern: "master"
          include: true
          source: true
      cancel_previous_builds: true
    scripts:
      - name: Check Dart Version
        script: |
          dart --version
      - name: Set up local.properties
        script: |
          echo "flutter.sdk=$HOME/programs/flutter" > "$CM_BUILD_DIR/android/local.properties"
      - name: Get Flutter packages
        script: |
          flutter packages pub get
      - name: Flutter analyze
        script: |
          flutter analyze
    artifacts:
      - build/**/outputs/**/*.apk
    publishing:
      email:
        recipients:
          - test@gmail.com
        notify:
          success: true
          failure: true
    cache:
      cache_paths:
        - $FLUTTER_ROOT/.pub-cache
```

It seems that no matter what script I use, I get this error:

```
Build failed :|
Step 3 script `Check Dart Version` exited with status code 1
```

Making the `codemagic.yaml` not to work on my side at all.
Any ideas what I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 2:

1. try to remove `$PWD` from `working_directory: $PWD/apps/test_app` line. It should use path starting from repository root or you can use `$CM_BUILD_DIR`
2. next you need to provide full path to the `dart` command because it's not in the system `$PATH`. This work fine:

```
$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/dart --version
```

`FLUTTER_ROOT` variable already pre-defined for you.

Comment: do i need to setup an environment variables? https://imgur.com/O5c3r73 it doesn't seem to recognize any script i place. also i've been trying any scripts from the different codemagic.yaml examples here (https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/codemagic-sample-projects/blob/main/flutter/flutter-android-and-ios-yaml-demo-project/codemagic.yaml). i still get the same issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer